# Eclipse Null Analysis weird type mismatch error

Tags: java, eclipse, null

I am learning to use Eclipse's Null Analysis in my project by enable annotation-based null analysis in `Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings`, but I have encountered a weird error when doing the following.

**1) Create 2 interfaces:**

```
public interface Book {}
```

and

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;
public interface BookService {
    public @NonNull Book getBook(Long id);
}
```

**2) Create 2 classes implementing the above interfaces:**

```
public class BookImpl implements Book {}
```

and

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    @Override
    public @NonNull Book getBook(Long id) {
        return new BookImpl(); //error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from BookImpl to Book"
    }
}
```

An error occurs at the statement `return new BookImpl();` that reads `Type mismatch: cannot convert from BookImpl to Book`.

**What is the cause of this error and how to solve it?**

**Additional Detail**

I use Java 8 and Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, version: Kepler Service Release 2.

**Update**

I have try eclipse Luna M7 Release (4.4.0M7) and no error appear.

The problem is likely because an eclipse's bug and it seem to be fixed in the new version as mentioned by @user3580294 in the comments below.

Comment: No error on my machine. Java 1.8.0_05, Eclipse 4.4 M7. Eclipse's null analysis has some bugs (even in the development version of the upcoming build, as I've found), and I'm guessing that this could be one of them. Try downloading the developer build and see if it works.

Comment: Also, another thing to try would be to turn off null analysis and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @user3580294 The error disappears if I turn off the null analysis.

Comment: Yep, it's an Eclipse bug then. Either upgrade Eclipse, ignore the error, or turn off null analysis. Not a whole lot you can do about IDE bugs...

Comment: Okay, I am trying the developer build as you suggested, and will report here if it works, thank you.